# NameError: name 'ULInt8' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7

PYTHON 2.7 win7  construct 2.9.45

after `from construct import *`，

I want to use ULInt8'， but it says： NameError: name 'ULInt8' is not defined

I also tried `from construct import (Construct, ConstructError, Struct, Bytes, Array,ULInt8, ULInt16, ULInt32, ULInt64)`

it says： ImportError: cannot import name ULInt8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Construct you are using is 2.9 
So its no more ULInt8, Its Int8ul now. Check https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html

Comment: which version of construct  having ULInt8 could be used by me?

Comment: You should be able to use it with construct version 2.5 Install it with
        pip install construct==2.5.5
Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Did you try replacing ULInt8 with Int8ul?

Comment: I have changed ULInt8 to Int8ul， error occurs：    Int8ul("Prefix"),
TypeError: 'FormatField' object is not callable

Comment: it says "ERROR: No matching distribution found for construct==2.5.5" so i go for 2.5.3